# In WPF, can I have a borderless window that has regular minimize, maximise and close buttons?

Tags: wpf, xaml

If you look at the Chrome browser when maximized, it has its tab headers right at the top of the window.  Can I do something similar?

Comment: What you'll want to do is draw stuff directly on the window frame (the non-client area). That is very possible with WPF; if you search around you may be able to find something you can use.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Absolutely, but you're going to have to remake those buttons yourself (it's not hard, don't worry).

In your MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window ...
        Title="" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Icon="../Resources/MyIcon.ico" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
        ...>
    <Canvas>
       <Button /> <!-- Close -->
       <Button /> <!-- Minimize -->
       <Button /> <!-- Maximize -->
       <TabControl>
           ...
       </TabControl>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Then you just have to place the Buttons and the TabControl as wished on the Canvas, and customize the look and feel.

EDIT: The built in commands for closing/maximizing/minimizing in .NET 4.5 are `SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand`/
`SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand`/`SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand`

So if you're using .NET 4.5, you can do:

```
<Window ...
        Title="" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Icon="../Resources/MyIcon.ico" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
        ...>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute_1" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_1" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute_1" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_2" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute_1" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_3" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Canvas>
       <Button Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" Content="Close" />
       <Button Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" Content="Maximize" />
       <Button Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" Content="Minimize" />
       <TabControl>
           ...
       </TabControl>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And in your C# code-behind:

```
    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute_1(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed_2(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this);
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed_3(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
    }
```

This will make close/maximize/minimize works exactly like with a regular window.
Of course, you may want to use `System.Windows.Interactivity` to move the C# into a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

The buttons you have to implement by yourself. Resizing and moving window you can still have if you set `WindowChrome.WindowChrome` attached property, setting `GlassFrameThickness="0"` will also remove the shadow:

```
<Window ...>
   <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
       <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0"/>
   </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
</Window>
```