# WindowChrome - Can't click buttons in titlebar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, titlebar

I have a custom WindowChrome style for my WPF app (ripped from here: http://www.bdevuyst.com/wpf-custom-title-bar-and-taskbar/).

Code here:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">

    <!-- Simple style without anything to remove the title bar -->
    <Style x:Key="Style.Window.WindowStyleNoneWithTaskbar.Base" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <shell:WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="1" >
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Simple style with system buttons upper right -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style.Window.WindowStyleNoneWithTaskbar.Base}" x:Key="Style.Window.WindowStyleNoneWithTaskbar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                            <Canvas Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                <Button x:Name="MinimizeButton"  Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="55" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Close" >
                                    <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.reduce}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="NormalizeButton" Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Visibility="Collapsed" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="30" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Restore" >
                                    <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.normal}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="MaximizeButton" Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="30"  WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Maximize" >
                                    <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.maximize}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="5" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Close" >
                                    <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.close}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
                                </Button>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="MaximizeButton" />
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="NormalizeButton" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I removed references to "shell:" because it's deprecated, but for some reason I am unable to click the buttons in the title bar. I downloaded the sample solution from the website I linked, and the buttons worked from me.

So next, I added the references to "shell" back, but I was still unable to click the buttons.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I pretty much completely copied the sample solution into my project and it *still* didn't work. I have IsHitTestVisibleInChrome set to "true" for each button but it's not making a difference.

I've tried several other, much more simple approaches, with basic buttons and no styling, all to no avail. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your command bindings that are the issue here. Don't bind the Command properties. Simply set them:

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Button x:Name="MinimizeButton"  Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="55" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Close" >
        <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.reduce}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="NormalizeButton" Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Visibility="Collapsed" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="30" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Restore" >
        <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.normal}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="MaximizeButton" Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="30"  WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Maximize" >
        <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.maximize}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Style="{DynamicResource Style.Button.Core.Transparent}" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Right="5" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Close" >
        <Rectangle Margin="2" Fill="{DynamicResource appbar.close}" Opacity=".5" Width="15" Height="15" />
    </Button>
</Canvas>
```

You will also need a command binding for each of the commands and execute them programmatically as suggested by @Louis Kottmann here:

[In WPF, can I have a borderless window that has regular minimize, maximise and close buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930633/in-wpf-can-i-have-a-borderless-window-that-has-regular-minimize-maximise-and-c)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll try this when I get home tonight

Comment: That fixed it. Also, I didn't add the codebehind command bindings as I should have. I'm used to doing that in the ViewModel. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Small addition to the correct answer. If you have something like:

```
<Button shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
```

And your buttons do not react to clicks - just REMOVE "shell:"

```
<Button WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
```

This will make them work