# WPF menu item not clickable with WindowStyle=None with WindowChrome

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a an application where I would like to hide the title bar and add a custom style to the overall look. However, when I add a menu it's not clickable if positioned in the top left corner of the window.

[image: Menu in top left not clickable]

If I add a 20 margin I am able to interact with the menu

[image: Working menu in top left with 20 margin]

**There seems to be some kind of padding at the top left of the window which prevents my click from registering. How can I get around this issue?**

Here is the code of the non-working example as a reference

```
<Window x:Class="MyFirstApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyFirstApplication"
        xmlns:sliderMenu="clr-namespace:SliderMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyFirstApplication" Height="450" Width="800" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1"
        AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="1">
            <MenuItem Header="_Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also have this in my cs code

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // This ensures that the window is always on top, doesn't always work but should be good enough
        this.Topmost = true;

        // Window chrome allows resize on all edges
        WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, new WindowChrome());
    }
```

Comment: What it the `sliderMenu`, how it's defined? I can't reproduce your problem with default menu

Comment: The slider menu is taken from here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26924/WPF-Slider-Menu but I don't need it to reproduce the issue. I was sure it was something in my xaml code, maybe I need to try it in a new project.

Comment: I can focus and press a menu item. Maybe you have a custom style for window somewhere, or something like that

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be caused by `WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, new WindowChrome());`. You are right @PavelAnikhouski

Comment: In this case you can try use `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"`. It works for buttons in window chrome, not sure about the menu. You can also have a look at existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905412/windowchrome-cant-click-buttons-in-titlebar) for the similar problem

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I appreciate the help. I tried to edit this question to make it more relevant but I see now that it could be a duplicate so I would move to close it.  Your suggestion worked.